# How to increase limits on activity attachments?

Tags: activities, developer, 4.6

Current (4.6.7) limits say that an activity can have up to 3 attachments, each being less than 2MB.

I need more, and a bigger file size limit.

**What are the obstacles to achieving this?**

- I can't see anything in the db schema that implies a limit per activity, so is it just the UI that imposes the number of file limits?
- The files are stored (I assume) in the `civicrm_file.document` field which is a `MEDIUM_BLOB` and can therefore store a file just under 4GB. (my requirements are only ~20MB.) Is that 2MB limit set in a PHP ini file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to configure it in your settings
/civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1

Comment: Genius! Thanks! Couldn't see the wood for the trees!

Answer (score 1):

As a side note you might also need to increase PHP limits for larger files